# php crypt generates different values

Tags: php, crypt

I'm have a problem with php crypt() function, it generates a different passwords

here is the code for adding a test user to the database:

```
    $hash = crypt('roms','rc');
    $data = array('username' => 'roms', 'password' => $hash, 'email' => 'roms@r.c');
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
```

And here is the login function:

```
// user login function
public function userLogin($username, $password){
    $results = $this->db->select('select * from users where username = :username',
    array(':username'=>$username));

    //  print_r($results);
      $pass = $results[0]->password;
    //  echo '<br>';
    //  echo  crypt('roms','rc');
    //  echo '<br>';
    //  echo $password;
    //  echo '<br>';
    //  echo $pass;

    if( (count($results) > 0) ){
        //echo ">0";
        if($pass == $password){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The result of the function:
it works but never passes the if($pass == $password) condition because the passed hash is different than the one stored in the database

```
// print_r($results);
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [username] => roms [password] => rc7y3Ie22wNUQ [email] => roms@r.c ) ) 

// echo crypt('roms','rc'); (crypt the original password)
rc7y3Ie22wNUQ

// echo $password; (passed to the function)
rcKGHUlyQfgrU

// echo $results[0]->password; (from the database)
rc7y3Ie22wNUQ
```

And here is the login function call

```
if(isset($_POST['user-login'])){

    $db = new DbHelpers();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = crypt($_POST['passowrd'],'rc');

    $bool = $db->userLogin($username, $password);
    if($bool){
        //echo "<script>alert('1');</script>";
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        \Helpers\Url::redirect('admin');
    }else{
        //echo "<script>alert('0');</script>";
        $data['login-error'] = '1';
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using [simple mvc framework](http://simplemvcframework.com/php-framework), it has a Password class for hashing passwords but I had the same problem when I used it. I also tried the md5 function.

Comment: [using error reporting would/should throw you an undefined index **passowrd** notice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: It's neither of those issues, the `crypt` function is generating a hash for an empty string possibly because the $_POST variable is incorrectly spelled. See my answer for evidence.

Comment: The input name was password, I changed it to pass and it worked. $password = crypt($_POST['pass'],'rc');

Comment: Should use a grain of salt like `CRYPT_SHA512`

Comment: *...and a dash of peppah!*

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variable is spelled incorrectly, and the hash you're generating is for an empty string

```
$password = crypt($_POST['passowrd'], 'rc');
```

Should probably be:

```
$password = crypt($_POST['password'], 'rc');
```

When I run:

```
echo crypt('', 'rc')
```

It outputs: `rcKGHUlyQfgrU`